# How to connect an Arduino via an ethernet cable to a laptop directly?

Tags: ethernet, arduino-leonardo, web-server

Maybe a silly question, because it is a usual topic, but I have a problem with my Arduino Leonardo ETH.

I want to create a web server on the Arduino with the example sketch `File > Examples > Ethernet > WebServer`. I plugged in the ethernet cable directly to my laptop. So there is no router or switch between them.

I also set the configuration to my ethernet port to the following IPv4 properties:
[image: Properties of internet protocol version 4]

Then in the example sketch, I changed the MAC address according to the bottom sticker of my Arduino.

```
byte mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x11, 0x33, 0xD6};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);
```

Now when I compile and upload the sketch to the Arduino, everything is working fine until it prints the IP address. According to the IP address which I have set in the code (`192.186.1.177`), it shows me `0.46.46.46` as you can see in the picture:

[image: Serial Monitor output]

This happens when I print that:

```
Serial.println("server is at ");
Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
```

Do you have any ideas how I could fix this? And why does it show me that invalid IP address?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using the correct type of cable? Might want to check that first.

Comment: @MikaelPatel I'm using a CAT. 5e S/UTP cable.

Comment: The Leonardo ETH has the W5500 Ethernet controller, which doesn't do auto-MDIX so you will need to use a crossover cable.

Comment: I am sure the Ethernet card in computer makes the auto-MDX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Ethernet2 library for W5500

Comment: Thank you very much. You've saved my day. For a reference, here's an example of implementation: http://platformio.org/lib/show/261/Ethernet2